# How to execute this query to compare dates

Tags: sql, date

Write a query to display the students who are older than 'Balakrishnan'. Sort the results based on firstname in ascending `order`.

The output should look like this

```
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| STUDID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |   STREET    |    CITY    |    DOB    |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|   3009 | Abdul     | Rahman   | HAL         | Bangalore  | 19-JAN-88 |
|   3002 | Anand     | Kumar    | Indiranagar | Bangalore  | 19-JAN-88 |
|   3001 | Dileep    | Kumar    | Jai Nagar   | Bangalore  | 10-MAR-89 |
|   3004 | Gowri     | Shankar  | Gandhipuram | Coimbatore | 22-DEC-87 |
|   3008 | John      | Dravid   | Mylapore    | Chennai    | 15-SEP-87 |
|   3006 | Prem      | Kumar    | Ramnagar    | Coimbatore | 17-MAY-87 |
|   3007 | Rahul     | Dravid   | KKNagar     | Chennai    | 08-OCT-87 |
+--------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hint:  Get the DOB for the student you care about.  Then use that in a `WHERE` clause for the rest of the query.

Comment: Where is 'Balakrishnan' in your table.

Comment: @S_sauden: the question only contains the *answer* to the query. So Balakrishnan cannot be older than him/herself...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks

Comment: I am new in sql so i tried ths select * from course c1 left outer join course c2 on c1.duration=c2.duration order by c1.coursename;

Comment: @S_sauden i have given the expected output table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-
It may be help you.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DOB < TO_DATE('DOB_of_Balakrishnan','DD-MM-YYYY')
ORDER BY FIRSTNAME;
```

I am using oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

As I see that the DOB of Balakrishnan is not provided...
try using this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE dob<(SELECT dob 
            FROM table_name
            WHERE LOWER(firstname)='bala')
ORDER BY firstname;
```